# wicket image path without rewrite

Tags: image, url, path, url-rewriting, wicket

I m trying to upload and show images.
I get the file, write it to docroot of glassfish application server, then

```
    Image image = new Image("myimage","images/task.gif");
```

But i get `<img wicket:id="myimage" src="resources/wickcat.MyPage/images/task.gif" />`

Is there any way that wicket wont rewrite my src path? Even when i use an http://.... starting src, it writes resources/wickcat.MyPage/http://... which makes no sense at all.
I just need it to write "images/task.gif".
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is two ways to do this.

1. Use `<img src="images/task.gif" />`. This is if you don't need reference to the component in the class.
2. Use `ContextImage image = new ContextImage("myimage", "images/task.gif");`. If you use the `ContextImage` component, the source will be relative to the Context root, you can even input a model as the relative path to the image.

Comment: nice tip this deserves vote, thanks for sharing this but my aim was to prevent wicket from rewriting my src path

Answer (score 1):

The `Image` class assumes the image is a resource located in the classpath.

You could use a `WebMarkupContainer` with a `SimpleAttributeModifier`:

```
WebMarkupContainer img = new WebMarkupContainer("myimage")
    .add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("src", "/images/task.gif"));
```

It will output the string as is, so you have complete control.

If it is used several times across the application, I'd recommend you to create a component encapsulating this behavior. Something like

```
public class MyImage extends WebMarkupContainer {
    public MyImage(String id, String path) {
        add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("src", path));
    }
}
```

Comment: should not it be new SimpleAttributeModifier("src","/images/task.gif"); ?
i forgot to add the root slash of the gif but you guessed it right :=)

Comment: i will accept this as answer after SimpleAttributeModifier's constructor's parameters are given in right way, i dont want a serial killer coder to read this false version, loss time and come after me :)

Comment: realized that this is a deprecated way :(

Comment: corrected. In the new version, it would be `AttributeModifier.replace("src",...)`